# ILog with OpenJDK

Tags: java, ilog

I am currently using IBM Decision Optimization Center V3.8 to create model file and recently changed to use OpenJDK. Can I ask whether will IBM Decision Optimization Center V3.8 work with OpenJDK?

I am using HTCondor to run the model file and the HTCondor kept holding on to the job, can someone give me some guide on how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) is a project supplying source code to implement the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Several vendors provide binary builds or installers based largely or entirely on the OpenJDK source code, for various host platforms. These vendors include: SAP, BellSoft, Azul Systems, Microsoft, Amazon, Oracle, Red Hat / IBM, Adoptium / AdoptOpenJDK, and more. These various builds/installers should all be able to run apps written in Java. Choose vendor based on their licensing terms, support options, & price (some free, some paid).

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK vs Oracle JDK... the only difference is in the licensing between these two.

**1st** is open source with gnu general license. **2nd** is commercial license.

some other diff's like support/extendibility/cost but nothing regarding it's code.

if you have a super critical application that touches millions then you would consider support etc. but most recommend to go for OpenJDK because code is 99% same

Comment: From what are you quoting?

Comment: i write my own text just get some idea from other's what do you mean exactly? @BasilBourque

Comment: You have formatted your text as a quote. Delete the `>` characters.